# Taxonomies page not found In the acf plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I used to use the [Custom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) plugin, There were no problems in this plugin and the structure was as follows :

```
site.com/portfolio/
site.com/portfolio/category/uncategorized/
```

[Advanced Custom Fields (ACF)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin has added the possibility of adding post type and Taxonomies, The [Advanced Custom Fields (ACF)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin has an option in the settings that allows you to transfer all post types and Taxonomies from the [Custom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) plugin to it. I did this, But Taxonomies page was not found. This is the output of [Advanced Custom Fields (ACF)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin.

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    register_post_type( 'portfolio', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'portfolio',
            'singular_name' => 'portfolio',
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'supports' => array(
            0 => 'title',
            1 => 'editor',
            2 => 'excerpt',
            3 => 'revisions',
            4 => 'thumbnail',
            5 => 'custom-fields',
        ),
        'taxonomies' => array(
            0 => 'portfolio-category',
        ),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'with_front' => false,
            'feeds' => false,
        ),
        'can_export' => false,
        'delete_with_user' => false,
    ) );
} );

add_action( 'init', function() {
    register_taxonomy( 'portfolio-category', array(
        0 => 'portfolio',
    ), array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'category',
            'singular_name' => 'category',
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'show_tagcloud' => false,
        'show_in_quick_edit' => false,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'portfolio/category',
            'with_front' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true,
        ),
    ) );
} );
```

Comment: I searched a lot, but I didn't get an answer, friends, please help me